# Running a Linux command from java

Tags: java, linux

I'm trying to run a command from java. But command is not executing. Can anyone pointout why?

```
 String path = dest+"/info_updated.csv";
     File file = new File(path);
    String command = "sed -i '/" + subscriberId + "/d' "+file;
    System.out.println("command "+command);

       Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();

          Process p = null;
          try {
            p = run.exec(command);

            InputStream errorStream = p.getErrorStream();
            p.waitFor();

          } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("ERROR.RUNNING.CMD");
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          } finally {
            p.destroy();
          }
          return true;
  }
```

In the log it is printing the command correctly.

```
command sed -i '/L13876110226750000/d' /usr/share/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/webapps/SMS/info_updated.csv
```

But it is not executing.

Comment: `-e` instead of or in addition to `-i` ?

Comment: define "not executing", any stacktrace? Also, this will most likely make tomcat redeploy the SMS webapp

Comment: No shell => no quoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `/bin/sh -c` before your command and have a try.

Like this:

```
String[] command = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "sed -i '/" + subscriberId + "/d' "+file};
Process p = run.exec(command);
```